# DBAction causes play server not responding

Tags: scala, playframework, play-slick

I was doing some simple testing with play-slick. I first used `DB.withSession {implicit s:Session => ...}` in `Global.scala`, and it works very well. Then I tried to use `DBAction{}` in my controller, and things start to fall apart.

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.db.slick._
import play.api.Play.current
import models._

object Main extends Controller {

  def index = DBAction { implicit s =>

      Articles.insert(Article(None,"title1", "hellothere", Some(timeStamp), Some(timeStamp), None))

    Ok(views.html.index.render("OK, It works"))
  }
}
```

The model looks like this (I'm skipping the `DAO` trait, case class, and the cake-pattern):

```
  object Articles extends DAO {

    /* Insert a new Article  */
    def insert(article: Article)(implicit s: Session) {
      Articles.insert(article)
    }

  }
```

I tried to run this program, and all I got was the forever server pending status. Everything else works fine, my `Global.scala` created all tables correctly, and if I remove that `Articles.insert()` clause, I get my view page. So I would say something must be wrong with this part: `DBAction { implicit s=> ...}`. I somehow feel like DBAction couldn't find the implicit session, and it keeps looking...which causes this forever pending response.

Well, I searched for it and still don't know what to do. Does anyone know what's wrong here and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBAction puts the session down a layer.  So in your code above "s" is actually getting set to the request.  You could call s.dbSession and get it that way.

```
def index = DBAction { request =>
  implicit val session = request.dbSession
  Articles.insert(Article(None,"title1", "hellothere", Some(timeStamp), Some(timeStamp), None))

  Ok(views.html.index.render("OK, It works"))
}
```

I had a similar issue and that is how I resolved it.  There has to be a better way to get the session though.  If someone else has a better suggestion I would like to know as well.